# Get tkinter listbox selected item when Enter is pressed, and close

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, keyboard-events

This code creates a `listbox`:

```
from tkinter import *
listbox = Listbox(Tk())
listbox.pack()
for item in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
listbox.select_set(0)
listbox.focus_set()
mainloop()
```

I'd like to close the `listbox` and get the index of the selected item when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed.

How to do this with `Tkinter`?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to get rid of the GUI completely, or just destroy the `Listbox` widget?

Comment: @HenryYik Get rid of the GUI completely indeed, and get the index of the selected item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first define an instance of `Tk`, which you can close it by calling `destroy`. To close the GUI by `ENTER`, bind an event to `<Return>`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
for item in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    listbox.insert("end", item)
listbox.select_set(0)
listbox.focus_set()

def exit_gui(event):
    global result
    result = listbox.curselection()
    root.destroy()

root.bind("<Return>",exit_gui)
root.mainloop()

print (result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `result = listbox.curselection()` gives a tuple `(1,)`, why not just an integer?

Comment: Because `Listbox` supports multiple selection if required. If you only do single selections, you can slice the result.